# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta que me muestre un registro de acuerdo a una condición específica?

Tags: mysql, sql, sas

Tengo esta tabla:

| COLUMN_X | COLUMN_Y |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1173 |
| A | 1174 |
| A | 1000000004 |
| B | 1173 |
| B | 1174 |
| C | 1173 |
| C | 1174 |
| D | 1173 |
| D | 1174 |
| E | 1173 |
| E | 1174 |
| F | 1173 |
| F | 1174 |
| G | 1173 |
| G | 1174 |
| G | 1000000004 |
| H | 1173 |
| I | 1173 |
| I | 1174 |
| J | 1173 |
| J | 1174 |

Y la consulta que quiero realizar debe crear una nueva columna COLUMN_Z, la cual va tener valores para cada COLUMN_X de acuerdo a la siguiente lógica:

- Si existe un COLUMN_Y con el valor igual a 1000000004, entonces COLUMN_Z será igual a Easy.
- Si no existe un COLUMN_Y con el valor igual a 1000000004, pero sí con el valor igual a 1174, entonces COLUMN_Z será igual a Medium.
- Y si no existe un COLUMN_Y con el valor igual a 1000000004 y tampoco igual a 1174, pero sí igual a 1173, entonces COLUMN_Z será igual a Hard.

La consulta que se espera obtener sería la siguiente:

| COLUMN_X | COLUMN_Y | COLUMN_Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1000000004 | Easy |
| B | 1174 | Medium |
| C | 1174 | Medium |
| D | 1174 | Medium |
| E | 1174 | Medium |
| F | 1174 | Medium |
| G | 1000000004 | Easy |
| H | 1173 | Hard |
| I | 1174 | Medium |
| J | 1174 | Medium |

Espero que alguno se pueda tomar un poco de tiempo para apoyarme y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL cuenta dentro de su sintaxis con ["CASE"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), con lo cual se puede establecer una lógica de control para la salida de datos devueltos por la consulta. Sugiero revises esta parte de la documentación.

En relación a tu caso, la consulta requerida podría ser así:

```
SELECT
COLUMN_X,
COLUMN_Y,
CASE WHEN COLUMN_Y = 1000000004 THEN 'Easy'
     WHEN COLUMN_Y = 1174 THEN 'Medium'
     WHEN COLUMN_Y = 1173 THEN 'Hard'
END AS COLUMN_Z
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Aunque si tienes valores en la COLUMN_Y distintos a 1000000004,1174 o 1173, puede ser conveniente usar ELSE dentro del CASE o especificar por medio del WHERE las condiciones para evitar estos registros.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
COLUMN_X,
COLUMN_Y,
CASE WHEN COLUMN_Y = 1000000004 THEN 'Easy'
     WHEN COLUMN_Y = 1174 THEN 'Medium'
     WHEN COLUMN_Y = 1173 THEN 'Hard'
END AS COLUMN_Z
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLUMN_Y IN (1000000004,1174,1173)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, estuve probando la lógica que me sugieres, sin embargo, obtengo la misma cantidad de registros. El objeto de la consulta que quiero realizar es que el número de registros se reduzca a solo un registro por  COLUMN_X, así como se muestra en la segunda tabla que compartí.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta en función de tu comentario, en esta segunda consulta se incluye la palabra reservada "DISTINCT" por lo que no se van a repetir los registros y se condiciona a que solo se muestren aquellos registros cuyo valor del campo COLUMN_Y se encuentren dentro de los tres valores que condicionan el campo COLUMN_Z. Sin embargo, si para la columna COLUMN_X tienes dos valores de "A" cuyos correspondientes partes en COLUMN_Y son diferentes (Ej. 1174 y 1173), ambos registros se mostraran indicando en el campo COLUMN_Z 'Medium' y 'Hard' respectivamente.